# What does "KHTML, like Gecko" mean in a user-agent string?

Tags: user-agent, gecko, layout-engine

I understand that [KHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML) is the [HTML Layout Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) used, but what significance does the "*like Gecko*" part have? Why is it there?

Is there a historical reason similar to the "*Mozilla*" part of the [User Agent String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Konqueror began to pretend to be "like Gecko" to get the good pages,
and called itself `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.2; FreeBSD) (KHTML, like Gecko)`.

For more information, read:

- Andersen, Aaron (September 3, 2008) -
  [History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) - WebAIM

Comment: In case you see this answer and are Konfused, Konqueror is the browser for KDE that WebKit is based on and Chrome and Safari are based on WebKit.

Comment: The "the good pages" @Melad is talking about, I learned, were pages with `frame`s and `iframe`s, which I guess are kinda like today's experimental CSS features, and the whole idea of saying "like Gecko" would I guess be like Firefox starting to obey `-webkit-` CSS vendor prefixes because Mozilla got tired of developers only including the `-webkit-` prefixed rules and leaving out the `-moz-` ones.

Comment: @JacobFord Couldn’t browsers other than Gecko and Konqueror understand `frame`s? Why couldn’t they get _good web code_ that Gecko gets?

Comment: @КонстантинВан Webmasters would program their servers to host different versions of their webpage depending on the browser's reported user agent string. Often it was as simple as checking if it contained the substring `Gecko`. Check that [history of the browser user-agent string](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) for a good folky history. If you want to adapt it into a banjo-heavy song, I'm in.

Comment: it was really a good read this link ... got a lot of laughts! I could not stay quiet as i read, just the way they wrote it was so funny; a "must read" more than many best sellers ...